# How do I make table cells fit the size of contained images?

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, xcode6

I'm trying to figure out how to make a table of images with varying sizes. Where the images get resized to fit the width of the device, and the cells fit the height of the image. Currently the images are getting sized to the table cells.

[image]

[Xcode project](https://bitbucket.org/matthewca/ios-auto-row-height/)

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

var images = ["abstract","city","city2","nightlife"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell
    cell.configureCellWith(images[indexPath.item])
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

}
```

ImageTableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class ImageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var tableImage: UIImageView!

func configureCellWith(image: String) {
    tableImage.image = UIImage(named: image)
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to set the cell height to the correct height for that cell's image.

(You can determine that height by examining the image's width and height, and divide to give the aspect ratio. Now use that aspect ratio to determine the height based on the cell width, which is the table width.)

Comment: Can you expand a bit on how to implement this?

Comment: I got this working by setting the Table View delegate to be the ViewController, than creating heightForRowAtIndexPath as you described. But I'm wondering if this can be done just by using auto layout. I've seen auto layout mentioned for this problem, but nothing has worked for me yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually fairly simple. You just have to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath function and return height of image for each cell.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return image[indexPath.row].size.height
}
```